# How to append an item to exiting json array? below is my json array

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

```
var jsonObject={"data":[{"Id":293,"SourceURL":"//jhthf/hsf/d$","TargetURL":"makemytriip.com","Status":"Failed","UserFriendlyName":"progress","MonthName":"November","StartYear":2020},
{"Id":296,"SourceURL":"//jhthf/hsf/f$","TargetURL":"usermobileapp.com","Status":"Success","UserFriendlyName":"progress","MonthName":"November","StartYear":2020}]}
```

How can I add one more parameter "entityType":"Value" and it's corresponding value in each item in this array? trying using Newtonsoft json( JObject -Add method) but it's giving
below errror

'Object serialized to Array. JObject instance expected.'

```
JObject jo = JObject.FromObject(jsonObject);
                            jo.Add("SiteOwnerDisplayNames", userDisplayNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is on FromObject? FromObject expects to be passed in a JObject.

Try using Json.Parse to convert the array to a JObject.

`JObject jo = JObject.FromObject(Json.Parse(jsonObject));`

The jsonObject you have is created with array syntax rather than being a properly create JObject[]

Comment: tried parsing using JObject parsedJsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonObject );but didn't work